# OpenShift Pro: How To Add Additional Folders to Tomcat's Document Base

Tags: java, tomcat, configuration, openshift

As we all know, this is done by adding a line to Tomcat's server.xml like this:

```
        <Context docBase="${ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE}/documents" path="/documents" />
```

In Openshift 2 this was achieved by editing **.openshift/config/server.xml**

I am migrating a web app from **OpenShift 2** to **OpenShift Pro** and I need to be able to replicate this requirement.

I tried editing **/opt/webserver/conf/server.xml** but the newly added line vanished after the redeployment. Obviously, it was overwritten by the process.

So, my question is:

**How to permanently change Tomcat's server.xml in OpenShift Pro?**

The object of the exercise is to be able to serve documents (PDFs or Images) from outside of Tomcat's webapp folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With each deployment, the server is rebuilt and changes to server.xml pr any server configuration file would be lost. So, all the config files should be part of the repo, from which the image is created.

If you are using maven build and would like a custom deployment of your own version of the config file like server.xml, check [this article](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html#serverXml)

Sample POM [given here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/maven-plugin/trunk/tomcat7-maven-plugin/src/test/resources/deploy-war-project/pom.xml).

Another hack is to create a folder called configuration under the top level git folder in your source code. Any file you put in there will get copied to: /opt/webserver/conf. It really is that simple, but not tried this.